# Issues with OAuth 2.0 Library for Google Apps Scripts for MEETUP

Tags: oauth, google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, meetup

I am using [OAuth 2.0 Library](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2) for Google Spreadsheet for [Meetup Api](http://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/auth/)

Code.gs

```
function getMeetupService() {  
  return OAuth2.createService('meetup')

      // Set the endpoint URLs, which are the same for all Google services.
      .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://secure.meetup.com/oauth2/authorize')
      .setTokenUrl('https://secure.meetup.com/oauth2/access')

      // Set the client ID and secret, from the Google Developers Console.
      .setClientId('.....')
      .setClientSecret('......')

      // Set the name of the callback function in the script referenced
      // above that should be invoked to complete the OAuth flow.
      .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')

      // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
      .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())

      .setTokenFormat(OAuth2.TOKEN_FORMAT.FORM_URL_ENCODED);

}
_eventId = null;
function startService(eventId) {
  var meetupService = getMeetupService();
  if (!meetupService.hasAccess()) {
    var authorizationUrl = meetupService.getAuthorizationUrl();
    return authorizationUrl;

  } else {
   //Yet to decide
  }
  return 123;
}

function authCallback(request) {
  var meetupService = getMeetupService();
  var isAuthorized = meetupService.handleCallback(request);
  if (isAuthorized) {
    //getAllDetails(_eventId);
  } else {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Denied. You can close this tab');
  }
}
```

Sidebar.html

```
    $(function() {
      checkService();
});
function checkService() {
    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(function(url) {
        if(url) {
        $('body').append('<a href="'+url+'" target="_blank">Click here to Login into Meetup</a>');
           $('#run-get-details').attr("onclick", 'window.open("' + url + '")');
        } else {
           $('#run-get-details').attr("url", '');
        }
        $('#run-get-details').prop("disabled", false);
    })
    .withFailureHandler(failureHandler)
    .startService($("#eventId").val());
}
function authCallback(request) {
  alert(123);
}
```

Everything seems to be working till the link. Once the link is clicked it opens the authentication window of the meetup exactly i want. But then once I authorize the app in meetup and when it gets redirected to script.google.com

> https://script.google.com/a/macros/{**domain**}/d/{**PROJECT_ID**}/usercallback?code={**code**}&state=ADEpC8wvspQd-+VXyQ0mOhYNenFu9Ib08hK6xfJ2gNJwcTxrIB4nVfphDyhejUHEMdgD0OhtwdcEs46KdhUZMD-Ekwftj3bzXwdi-mKc8PLKd7SsAYYqE-ZVZD2tm1HmyxtKYJCkoeg7R1K5DIMedYp38BiJ4F2Hbtei34fEdveObQhMSMDt1f2ufrmDzGh5W+fxdXMEmrfeCINO23hC8yV0JRXVDkErL3t8pQih8DicQoY6k2uqHThK8BqfSioBkgPZ0SPvj3Krtpgj9R+XWGtPqRRAwPum4k8etMROvy2DLT1ENNJdrVw

But then its throwing the error

> The state token is invalid or has expired. Please try again.

Someone please help me in this.

Comment: Token format for this api is json

Answer (score 0):

So looking into this a bit further I found the issue. The Meetup server is changing the state token. If you copy your token from  getAuthorizationUrl() and paste it into the state parameter in the url of the bad callback the Auth flow will successfully continue.

State Token made by Apps Script

```
ADEpC8zI8-E38GrIi2sB5Pf1xK2Hn-6XQ-SJLa0gmxos6z-hbvedTJ2UvXzSJxXbE_NfJlpHkOsjN4DLJ0sOGsYIZpTBc3OpAMWuoj-8UjUuKcTs1htZknyzv0QX9pPe-McxB_MC1fbGBjvrwEGP5_58tQdfRf3K70LURbe0cZ2qx_YK5xxN2qE
```

Returned State Token

```
ADEpC8zI8-E38GrIi2sB5Pf1xK2Hn-6XQ-SJLa0gmxos6z-hbvedTJ2UvXzSJxXbE+NfJlpHkOsjN4DLJ0sOGsYIZpTBc3OpAMWuoj-8UjUuKcTs1htZknyzv0QX9pPe-McxB+MC1fbGBjvrwEGP5+58tQdfRf3K70LURbe0cZ2qx+YK5xxN2qE
```

Comment: I posted an issue on their github page.  Nothing that can be done on the Apps Script side I don't think.  You can do the paste the currect state into the callback url method if you need a token for testing.  It worked for me.